# 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression' with INSERT INTO non-query

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to insert values into a database, but am coming across the aforementioned error at this part of the code:

```
                Dim InsertUser As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [User] ([User ID], [User Name], [Total Score]) VALUES (@NO,'@Tid',@Sid);", DatabaseConnection)
            InsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NO", NumberOfUsers + 1)        
            InsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tid", txtUserName.Text)        
            InsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sid", CInt(lblScore.Text))     
            InsertUser.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

[User ID] and [Total Score] are numbers, and [User Name] is short text in the database, and NumberOfUsers is an integer. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Just Remove the single quotes from '@Tid'

Comment: you are a saint

Comment: There's more to address here than just that one fix.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed several things:

- There is an extra set of single quotes in the SQL string around `@Tid`.
- OleDb does not generally support named parameters (there are exceptions for a few providers, but typically you need to use `?` for the place holders)
- We don't see where you open the connection.
- Better to avoid `AddWithValue()` for an `Add()` overload that is specific about database types and lengths. This helps performance and avoids problems caused by bad database type conversions
- Use a separate new connection object for most queries that is only open for the minimum time possible (typically controlled via a Using block). With OleDb, this helps limit contention/blocking for tables and helps reduce database corruption.

This code includes those fixes:

```vb
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO [User] ([User ID], [User Name], [Total Score]) VALUES (?, ?, ?);"
Using DatabaseConnection = New OleDbConnection("connection string here"), _
      InsertUser As New OleDbCommand(sql, DatabaseConnection)

    'Guessing at columns types. Use actual column types and lengths from the database
    InsertUser.Parameters.Add("@NO", OleDbType.Integer).Value = NumberOfUsers + 1   
    InsertUser.Parameters.Add("@Tid", OleDbType.VarWChar, 20).Value = txtUserName.Text        
    InsertUser.Parameters.Add("@Sid", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(lblScore.Text)
    DatabaseConnection.Open()  
    InsertUser.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```